# Multiple dynamic JCarousels on window and onclick scroll is not working

Tags: jcarousel

I have a page with 2 carousels, each invoked with a unique ID.  The carousels work fine.  I have a div on the page that i want to click and have the first carousel, #first, scroll using the scroll method.   When i have one carousel on the page the scroll method, bedRoomClick, works fine.
When I add the second carousel,  #second, the scroll method in bedRoomClick() no longer works.  I receive the error, 
     Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).data(...).scroll is not a function.

If I delete the second carousel everything works fine (no error and scrolling works).  Any thoughts/suggestions?

How i created my carousel

```
    jQuery('#first').jcarousel({
     wrap: 'circular',
     visible: 3
});
jQuery('#second').jcarousel({
    wrap: 'circular',
    rtl:rtl,
    visible: 4
});
```

The script with the scroll method

```
    <script>
    function bedRoomClick() {
       var instance =  jQuery('#first').data('jcarousel');
       jQuery('#first').data('jcarousel').scroll('+=2');
    }
</script>
```

The div clicked

```
<div class="banner" onclick="bedRoomClick();"></div>
```